# Using ffmpeg in bash

Tags: bash, terminal, ffmpeg, lame

I'm trying to make a bash script to transcode .wav files to mp3 (with lame V0 preset) within a directory. Here's what I have so far

```
#!/bin/bash
#
for abc in *.wav; do
  name=${abc%.*}
  echo "$name"
  ffmpeg -i "$abc" -ac 2 -f wav - | lame -V 0 - "$name.mp3"
done
#
```

Where the first **do** line cuts out the extension so I can use the file name later.

I've tested the ffmpeg command on a single file but once I include it in the **for** loop I get the following error (for the last track):

```
10 Artist - track
lame: excess arg Artist
ffmpeg version 0.8.6-4:0.8.6-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the Libav developers
  built on Apr  2 2013 17:00:59 with gcc 4.6.3
10: No such file or directory
```

I'm not sure why there is an excess argument for the **lame** line, or why ffmpeg is looking only at a file named "10". Is there something I'm missing?

Many thanks for any help

Comment: Try quoting the variables  to avoid [*word splitting*](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting), e.g. `ffmpeg -i "$abc" -ac 2 -f wav - | lame -V 0 - "$name.mp3"`

Comment: Damn, that always catches me out, thank you!